# How to set array in jsonobject

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Unable to set array inside JSONObject according to the response.Below is my code in which I am unable to set array in jsonobject. How to send key value for array inside my jsonobject  for which shared the response which code is getting from postman

Is this the right way in code

Code--

```
     JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
            array.add(productId);
            array.add(qty);
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("productDetails", array);**
```

This is the code in MainActivity. The problem is not getting correct jsonarray in my JSON object so API will not hit correctly
These String key values are used to pass in request params

```
    String key="WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz";
            String affId="teamfotog";
            String act="photoStores";
            String latitude="40.7127753";
            String longitude="-74.0059728";
            String devinf="Android,7.0";
            String appver="1.00";
            String productId="6670002";
            String qty="3";
            //productDetails
            **JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
            array.add(productId);
            array.add(qty);**

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("apiKey", key);
                jsonObject.put("affId", affId);
                jsonObject.put("act", act);
                jsonObject.put("latitude", latitude);
                jsonObject.put("longitude", longitude);
                jsonObject.put("devinf", devinf);
                jsonObject.put("appver", appver);
                **jsonObject.put("productDetails", array);**

    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    ApiStorePhotoInterface apiInterface = ApiStorePhotoClient.getApi();

    Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString().trim()));
```

Request Params is in Jsonbody --

```
{"apiKey":"WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz","affId":"teamfotog","act":"photoStores","latitude":"40.7127753","longitude":"-74.0059728","devinf":"Android,7.0","appver":"1.00","productDetails":[{"productId":"6670002","qty":"3"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it won't work. You are directly adding objects(`Strings`) in your `JsonArray`. In the response body, what you really want is a `JsonObject` inside the `JsonArray`. Try this -

```
JsonObject productDetail = new JsonObject();
productDetail.addProperty("productId", productId);
productDetail.addProperty("qty", qty);

JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add(productDetail);
```

Comment: So I have to create new jsonobject for this ?

Comment: JSONArray is not working but JsonArray is working with null response

Comment: From response body, you can see that it's an array of objects.

Comment: {
 "apiKey": "WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz",
 "affId": "teamfotog",
 "act": "photoStores",
 "latitude": "40.7127753",
 "longitude": "-74.0059728",
 "devinf": "Android,7.0",
 "appver": "1.00",
 "productDetails": "[\"{\\\"productId\\\":\\\"6670002\\\",\\\"qty\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\"]"
}   getting this from debugging

Comment: expected --{
 "apiKey": "WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz",
 "affId": "teamfotog",
 "act": "photoStores",
 "latitude": "40.7127753",
 "longitude": "-74.0059728",
 "devinf": "Android,7.0",
 "appver": "1.00",
 "productDetails": [{
  "productId": "6670002",
  "qty": "3"
 }]
}

Comment: Ok, so the structure is correct, but due to library mismatch, you are getting backslashes. What is your import statement for JsonArray?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are mixing different classes, `JSONObject`, `JsonObject`, `JSONArray` and `JsonArray`. Either use `com.google.gson` or `org.json` classes. Don't mix. So now try to replace `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();` with `JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();`

Comment: jsonObject.put("apiKey", key); my put method don't work now

Comment: Use `jsonObject.addProperty("apiKey", key);` for `Strings` and `jsonObject.add("apiKey", key);` for array.

Comment: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'com.google.gson.JsonElement' less... 
Inspection info:
add
(String,
com.google.gson.JsonElement)
in JsonObject cannot be applied
to
(String,
java.lang.String)    for this---- jsonObject.add("apiKey", key); for key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192953/discussion-between-ranjan-and-ankit-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
jsonObject.put("productDetails",(Object)array);
```

Comment: getting this request from debbuger ---

Comment: {
 "apiKey": "WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz",
 "affId": "teamfotog",
 "act": "photoStores",
 "latitude": "40.7127753",
 "longitude": "-74.0059728",
 "devinf": "Android,7.0",
 "appver": "1.00",
 "productDetails": "[\"{\\\"productId\\\":\\\"6670002\\\",\\\"qty\\\":\\\"3\\\"}\"]"
}

Comment: Expected --{
 "apiKey": "WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz",
 "affId": "teamfotog",
 "act": "photoStores",
 "latitude": "40.7127753",
 "longitude": "-74.0059728",
 "devinf": "Android,7.0",
 "appver": "1.00",
 "productDetails": [{
  "productId": "6670002",
  "qty": "3"
 }]
}

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still having problems with this, this is what fixed it for me:

Use:

```
JSONArray
```

istead of

```
JsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put product detail model to array

```
            String key="WSEoaGBifOEIS5dd6vQ5tfbs3R1c8Rsz";
            String affId="teamfotog";
            String act="photoStores";
            String latitude="40.7127753";
            String longitude="-74.0059728";
            String devinf="Android,7.0";
            String appver="1.00";
            String productId="6670002";
            String qty="3";     

            JsonObject product = new JsonObject();
            product.put("productId",productId);
            product.put("qty",qty);


            JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
            array.add(product);


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("apiKey", key);
            jsonObject.put("affId", affId);
            jsonObject.put("act", act);
            jsonObject.put("latitude", latitude);
            jsonObject.put("longitude", longitude);
            jsonObject.put("devinf", devinf);
            jsonObject.put("appver", appver);
            jsonObject.put("productDetails", array);
```